# Лабораторная работа C++

Tags: c++

Делаю свою первую лабораторную по С++ по учебнику
Задание
[image]
Вот мой код (среда разработки Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

double a, b, c, XStart, XEnd, deltaX;
cout << "Введите a = ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Введите b = ";
cin >> b;
cout << "Введите c = ";
cin >> c;
cout << "Введите начальное значение XStart = ";
cin >> XStart;
cout << "Введите начальное значение XEnd = ";
cin >> XEnd;
cout << "Введите deltaX = ";
cin >> deltaX;

bool check = true;
if((((int)a | (int)b) & ((int)a | (int)c)) != 0) {check = false;}
cout << "check = " << check;

double F;
cout <<  "\n-----------------\n";
cout << "F\t|x\t|\n";
cout <<  "-----------------\n";
for (double x = XStart; x <= XEnd; x += deltaX)
{
    if ( (x < 0) && (b != 0))
    {
        F = x*pow(x,2)+b;
    }
    else 
    {
        if ((x > 0) && (b = 0))
        {
            F = (x - a)/(x - c);
        }

        else 
        {
            F = x/c;
        }
    }
if(check) { F = (int) F;}
cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << F;
cout <<  "\t|";
cout << x;
cout <<  "\t|\n";
cout <<  "-----------------\n";
}

system("PAUSE"); 
return 0;
}
```

Не могу разобраться, зачем нужна проверка
`(((int)a | (int)b) & ((int)a | (int)c))`
 ?
и все ли у меня правильно по коду?

Comment: как же это может быть Ваш код, если Вам непонятна проверка, которая кстати, упоминается в условии задачи?

Comment: @KoVadim это можно объяснить разве что [синдромом доктора Стрэйнджлава][1]
Вы же не думаете, что ТС предоставил здесь чужой код, выдавая его за свой?

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_hand_syndrome

Comment: просто не могу понять, что эта проверка дает кроме того того, что просто добавляет одно условие в код.

Comment: это не проверка. Это задание такое. А они (задания) часто жуткие и беспощадные.

Comment: ну я уже так и понял что это просто чтобы было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навскидку:

1. `if ((x > 0) && (b = 0))` Косяк. В C/C++ оператор `=` выполняет присваивание, причём срабатывает он даже в условиях. То есть, вы при вычислении условия присваиваете `b` значение 0, а так как в C 0 интерпретируется как `false`, то выражение `(x > 0) && (b = 0)` будет всегда ложным и в блок `if` выполнение никогда не зайдёт. Для сравнения используется оператор `==`.
2. `F = x*pow(x,2)+b;` Невнимательность. Сравните формулу в задании и то, что вы написали.
3. `if((((int)a | (int)b) & ((int)a | (int)c)) != 0) {check = true;}` можно заменить на `check = ((int)a | (int)b) & ((int)a | (int)c)`.
4. Вы выводите на экран только значение последней итерации цикла. В задании указано выводить значение функции на каждой итерации.
5. Что значит не можете разобраться, зачем нужна проверка? Вы хоть задание читали прежде чем скопипастить решение? В задании чётко сказано:

> функция F должна принимать
> действительное значение если [выполняется условие], и целое в противном случае.

Comment: 1, 2 - по невнимательности накосячил, 3 - спасибо, исправил, 4 - нет, у меня выводятся все значения. потому что вывод сделан до последней закрывающей `}`. 5 - просто не могу понять, что эта проверка дает кроме того того, что просто добавляет одно условие.

Comment: 4 - ок, я ошибся. На будущее, активнее пользуйтесь отступами, так легче понять, где начинается и заканчивается блок кода.

5 - смотрим на строчку `if(check) { F = (int) F;}`. Здесь выполняется проверка и выполнение заявленного в задаче условия. Помним, если условие `((int)a | (int)b) & ((int)a | (int)c)` истинно, то результат функции должен быть целым. _Зачем_ такое условие в задаче - это уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: я вот и не мог понять зачем это условие нужно.

Comment: Это бред воспалённого сознания автора методички. Поверьте, это ещё не самое страшное условие, которое могут поставить в учебной задаче.